# How do I edit resolv.conf?

Tags: linux, dns

I need to setup OpenDNS, but I can't edit `resolv.conf`

```
Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search gateway.2wire.net
```

Comment: `sudo vi resolv.conf`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your system uses resolvconf, so the resolv.conf file is replaced by a symbolic link to `/etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf` and resolvconf dynamically generated the file. That's why `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`

To properly update the information in the file, you can put the dns-* parameters in `/etc/network/interfaces` e.g.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 33.33.13.10
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 33.33.13.1
     dns-nameservers 33.33.13.1 12.34.56.78
     dns-search example.com
```

Then, you can update the dns-* info by

```
$ resolvconf -d eth0
$ resolvconf -a eth0
```

Or you can do ifdown & ifup and resolvconf -d, -a will happen behind the scenes.

Note: sometimes I find resolvconf -u doesn't work. I don't know why

You should read `man resolvconf`. There's more information about all this.

TIP: if you want to update /etc/resolv.conf manually, you can remove the symlink and create /etc/resolv.conf by hand. This way, the file won't get updated from resolvconf ever.

```
    $ rm /etc/resolv.conf         ;# to remove the symlink
    $ vi /etc/resolv.conf         ;# to create a regular file
```

Comment: I went for the TIP at the end, seems to work like a charm. But just in case, as a first step I preferred `mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.disabled` instead of `rm`. Just in case I need to put the simlink back :)

Comment: The last one worked for me. While probably not ideal solution, this one at least works. Thank you, I tried like 4 or 5 different solutions until I found this one. You saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 11):

This usually requires editing `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`(depending on your distro this placement may vary slightly) or other files in this directory. They are added by the resolvconf process itself. The format of those files is the same as a standard resolv.conf.

After you have made those edits then you can force resolvconf to update using the command `resolvconf -u`.

Comment: Linux rwilson-Inspiron-1318 3.8.0-31-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 19:56:49 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

My system has the file "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base" but it's
empty

Comment: it just includes what is in that file along with other entries it calculates dynamically.  add your entry there as you would for normal `resolv.conf` file and after you run the command it should update what you see in resolv.conf and do what you need.